# Protected Static Method Access

Tags: java, static, lucene, protected

I am trying to use a protected static method in the Lucene information retrieval api. My understanding of static is that they are accessed from the class definition and my understanding of the protected keyword is that they can only be accessed from instances of that class or the subclass. So how exactly do you access a static protected method? Is my understanding mistaken? I am trying to call a protected static method from a library in an imported jar. How would I do that?

In this case I am calling the loadStopwordSet from [StopwordAnalyzerBase](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/StopwordAnalyzerBase.html)

Comment: hmmm, I don't get it why a method should be both protected and static. static method should be "stand alone". anyways if you trying to access this method, the class that you are trying to call it from should extend the super class that static method is in.

Comment: @nafas That was my thought too but I have to use Lucene and that is how it is written

Comment: hey, I've updated my comment. hope that is helpful

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/229220/what-is-difference-between-protected-static-method-and-protected-method

Comment: @nafas I am calling it from the class where it is defined StopwordsAnalyzerBase

Comment: check out that link, it is well explained.(Though still I'm not a fan of it )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you call this method by referring to it as `StopwordAnalyzerBase.loadStopwordSet(params)` ?

Consider this example (which compiles and works on my machine):

```
package p1;

public class C1 {
    protected void nonStatic() {}
    protected static void isStatic() {}
}

----
package p2;

import p1.C1;

public class C2 extends C1 {
   public void someMethod() {
     super.nonStatic();
     C1.isStatic();     // or even C2.isStatic()
   }
}
```

Getting back to your original question, I can see that this method is called from within ArabicAnalyzer:78 (Lucene version 4.9.0, package `org.apache.lucene.analysis.ar`) as well as many others.

Comment: Took a minute to understand but I get it. I need to call the static method inside the extending class

Answer (score 2):

The "Base" part of the class name should give you a hint: this is meant to be called from a subclass of StopwordAnalyzerBase
It is static because it need not be an instance method (it is self-contained and does not alter the state of the object that calls it). Looking at the API doesn't tell me why it would be protected, though - apart from following the minimum privilege principle, I suppose

Comment: I tried calling it from EnglishAnalyzer which extends the base and eclipse said it still wasn't visible